# Python Selenium does not work with WebDriverWait

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to log in to Google with Selenium. It works if I use sleep() like this code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://admin.google.com/')

emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Email')
emailElem.send_keys('mymail')
nextButton = browser.find_element_by_id('next')
nextButton.click()

sleep(5)
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Passwd')
passwordElem.send_keys('mypass')
signinButton = browser.find_element_by_id('signIn')
signinButton.click()
```

If I change sleep to WebDriverWait like this

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://admin.google.com/')

emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Email')
emailElem.send_keys('mymail')
nextButton = browser.find_element_by_id('next')
nextButton.click()


passwordElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by_id('Passwd'))
)
passwordElem.send_keys('mypass')
signinButton = browser.find_element_by_id('signIn')
signinButton.click()
```

It shows an error like this:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="Passwd"]

How can I use WebDriverWait?

Comment: It cannot be `NoSuchElementException`. In case of `WebdriverWait` + `ExpectedConditions` you should get `TimeOutException`! Are you sure that you show us correct code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as [Guy said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530940/python-selenium-does-not-work-with-webdriverwait/41532228#41532228), your `browser.find_element_by_id('Passwd'))` is not neccesary. Change to`((By.ID, "Passwd")))` as shown in [the documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp). Here's what the code should be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://admin.google.com/')

emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('youremail@example.com')
emailElem.send_keys('youremail')
nextButton = browser.find_element_by_id('next')
nextButton.click()


passwordElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Passwd")))

passwordElem.send_keys('yourpassword')
signinButton = browser.find_element_by_id('signIn')
signinButton.click()
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use `browser.find_element` inside `expected_conditions` (that is why you get `NoSuchElementException` instead of `TimeOutException`). The correct way to use it is `(By.ID, "id")`

```
passwordElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Passwd"))
)
```